# how to change JComponent Properties in a method

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I'm trying to write a GUI that has elements (specifically JLabels and a JButton) that I would like to change, add, delete, etcetera. However, Java is telling me that all modifiers for these objects are invalid (except final) which means that I can't reference these objects outside of where they are defined.  My question is, how can I set this up such that I can manipulate these elements later on?

Should it be relevant, my GUI is a JFrame containing a menu bar, a canvas, and a panel (which has the elements that I would like to manipulate).

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You are going to have to post some of your code. The RELEVANT parts. Otherwise any answer is just a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

> Java is telling me that all modifiers for these objects are invalid

From this description it would appear that you are creating components locally that need to be accessed elsewhere,  for instance in an `ActionListener` class.

I would suggest not to create any components that that belong to the `JFrame` or GUI container or in a local scope e.g. `main` method, that may need to be accessed later.
The simple example below shows how the component `label1` can be accessed easily by inner class `ButtonAction`:

```
public class SwingExample extends JFrame {
    private JButton button1;
    private JLabel label1;

    public SwingExample() {
        super("SwingExample");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 300);
        button1 = new JButton("Test");
        button1.addActionListener(new ButtonAction());
        label1 = new JLabel("Swing Example", JLabel.CENTER);
        add(label1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(button1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // don't create any locally scoped components here
        new SwingExample().setVisible(true);
    }

    class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction  {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label1.setText("label1 Accessed through global variable");
        }
    }
}
```